# Missing provisioning profile during app distribution

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, app-store-connect, testflight

I am trying distribute an app via xcode but I am still getting following errors:

```
1. Team "XXXX" does not have permission to create "iOS App Store" provisioning profiles. Select a different team and try again.
2. No profiles for 'ABC' were found. Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Store provisioning profiles matching 'ABC'.
```

In signing section everything looks good.

I am desperate about it and I don't know how I can solve it. At this moment I tried lot of things and I have still same issue. The app is written in Flutter.

Do you have any ideas how I can solve it or what I can do? I have a developer role in the team.

Comment: how you followed the official docs line by line? https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: you should be on a team or owner of the Apple Developer account to download your provisioning profiles to be able to distribute the app.